# Things to be aware of when using a container as a parent instead of MaterialApp/Scaffold

Tags: flutter, containers, flutter-layout, scaffold

Say I'm building an app that doesn't need Material design elements and use a container as a parent.

Are there things that need to be set up manually (layout-wise) that's unnecessary when using MaterialApp/Scaffold?

Following are few unexpected behaviors I noticed when using a container as a parent:
• Yellow lines in Text widgets (These lines disappear when using Scaffold instead)
• ClipRRect widget takes up the full screen even when I set constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Material** class is a main component of your UI. Using a **Material** Widget as parent doesn't mean you are forced to use **Material Design** for your entire app, you can do your own custom Widgets, UI, etc.

As part of the official documentation:

```
The Material widget is responsible for:

Clipping: If clipBehavior is not Clip.none, Material clips its widget sub-tree to the shape specified by shape, type, and borderRadius. By default, clipBehavior is Clip.none for performance considerations.
Elevation: Material elevates its widget sub-tree on the Z axis by elevation pixels, and draws the appropriate shadow.
Ink effects: Material shows ink effects implemented by InkFeatures like InkSplash and InkHighlight below its children.
```

It is also responsible of providing default styles for your Texts (that's why you're seeing the yellow underline).

Still, remember that you're making apps for mobile clients, therefore, you should be using some of the best practices that **MaterialApp** and **CupertinoApp** bring out of the box, even if you decide to take your own path inside the app, using your own custom **Widgets**, etc

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer helped you, remember to mark it as correct to help others with the same doubts.